# Google Maps API v3 travelMode as variable

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to pass values from a HTML form (the values are from radio button input) to my google maps API script. I can console.log the travelMode and it looks correct and should be working, but I keep getting this error: "Uncaught InvalidValueError: in property travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING". If I take out the variable and directly input the driving mode, it works fine.

What gives? here's my code I can supply more if needed:

```
// Get the travel method
  if (document.getElementById('bicycle').checked) {
    var method = "google.maps.TravelMode.BICYCLING";
  } else if (document.getElementById('motorcycle').checked) {
    var method = "google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING";
  } else {
    var method = "google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING";
  };

  console.log(method);

  var request = {
      origin: start,
      destination: end,
      travelMode: method,
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove quotes

```
  if (document.getElementById('bicycle').checked) {
    var method = google.maps.TravelMode.BICYCLING;
  } else if (document.getElementById('motorcycle').checked) {
    var method = google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING;
  } else {
    var method = google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING;
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
var method = 'DRIVING';

var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[method]
};
```

Comment: This also works, and I learned something new, I didn't realize you could pass variables to the request in that format. Thank You!

Comment: IMO, this is "cleaner" than the answer you accepted, but hey, that's up to you now ;-)

Comment: Because I'm still going to use the script to differentiate which method the user chose, I thought that having the entire Transit Mode passed to the request would be more efficient. BUT, I'm still learning and trying to get better with JavaScript, which method would be the best practice?